# CocoaPods equivalent for Microsoft .Net

Tags: .net, dependency-management, cocoapods

Is there an equivalent of [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) for Microsoft .Net (C#, VB, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used **CocoaPods** but seems like it does the same job as **NuGet** introduced with Visual Studio 2012.